# Access all the elements of matrix from a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of lists e.g: `c=Table[i+j,{i,5},{j,5}]`
and `a={1,2,3};b={3,2,5};`
Now I want to access the elements of `c` from `a,b`. Eg. I want
`c[[a[[1]],b[[1]]]],c[[a[[2]],b[[2]]]],c[[a[[3]],b[[3]]]]` etc. I have a very big `c, a,b` lists. All I want is to access the `c` elements just like above from `a,b`. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Does one of the answers below answer your question? If so, please accept one by clicking the grey checkmark next to the answer! If not, please explain why not by commenting on the answers!

Answer (score 4):

From `J. M. is back`:

```
Extract[c, Transpose[{a, b}]]
```

Here's some other ways:

```
Table[c[[a[[i]], b[[i]]]], {i, 1, Length@a}]
c[[##]] & @@@ Transpose[{a, b}]
MapThread[c[[##]] &, {a, b}]
Outer[c[[##]] &, a, b] // Diagonal
```

By the way, don't use the last one. It does *way* too many unnecessary calculations.

Comment: Another one for your list: `Extract[c, Transpose[{a, b}]]`

Comment: @J.M.isback. Wasn't familiar with that one! Thanks. (For some reason I've avoided `Extract`.) By the way, does the "is back" mean that you have a computer again?

Comment: Yes, yes, I do. Finally. :)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Inner`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inner.html)

```
c = Table[i + j, {i, 5}, {j, 5}]

(*  {{2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, {4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, {5, 6, 7, 8, 
  9}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}}  *)

a = {1, 2, 3}; b = {3, 2, 5};

Inner[c[[#1, #2]] &, a, b, List]

(*  {4, 4, 8}  *)
```

Or slightly simplified

```
Inner[c[[##]] &, a, b, List]


c = Array[x, {5, 5}];

Inner[c[[#1, #2]] &, a, b, List]

(*  {x[1, 3], x[2, 2], x[3, 5]}  *)
```

Or again, slightly simplified

```
Inner[c[[##]] &, a, b, List]
```